# Ants making my life miserable can I kill them

Tags: islamic-philosophy, animals

Like in title said my life become miserable because of they come to my bed every time. Sometimes when sleep I weak I find a lot of ants bitting my face and head. I become so angry that I want to kill them all.

Comment: This is relevant and maybe even includes an answer for your inquiry https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2356/getting-rid-of-ants-and-insect-islamic-way