# Can we kill those animals which can be harmful for us?

Tags: animals

Can we kill those animals which can be harmful for us like Scorpion etc. Does Islam give us permission for this?

Comment: [This post](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2356/getting-rid-of-ants-and-insect-islamic-way) seems relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is permissible to kill creatures that may cause harm, including scorpions. There are ahadith which explicitly state this:

> خمس فواسق يقتلن في الحل والحرم الحية والغراب الأبقع والفأرة والكلب العقور والحديا
>
> Five are the harmful things which should be killed in the sanctuary or otherwise: snake, speckled crow, rat, rabid dog and kite
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/15/72)</sup>

> خمس فواسق يقتلن في الحرم الفأرة والعقرب والحديا والغراب والكلب العقور
>
> Five kinds of animals are mischief-doers and can be killed even in the sanctuary: They are the rat the scorpion, the kite, the crow and the rabid dog.
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/120)</sup>